# Перевод тектового формата времени в эпохи Unix

Tags: python

Есть следующие варианты текстового представления  времени:

```
12.03.2019 в 13:00
14.02.2019  12:00
```

**Задача:**

Требуется перевести тестовый формат времени в эпохи Unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенным модулем datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime
tik = datetime.strptime('04.03.2019 18:55', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
print(tik.timestamp())
```

> 1551714900.0

Comment: а если попадается что-то такое: 05.03.2019 (МСК+7)? Как очистить такую строку от всего лишнего? Как вообще можно очистить строку от ненужной информации если она будет попадаться?

Comment: На мой взгляд, самый простой способ - применить регулярные выражения. Что-то навроде `re.findall(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4}', '05.03.2019 (МСК+7)')`. Но нужно знать заранее все возможные форматы, в которых может встречатся дата и время.